# animationset button after fade in not clickable

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile

i am just trying to fade in my imagebuttons in my app. The problem is however, that the imagebuttons are fading in but are not clickable afterwards. That means the onclickevents are not started when clicking on them, while they are shown.
is it because i set the original place of the buttons to layout_marginleft:-100dp;
and is there a way to get it to work even when i set the margin to -100dp?
Can you tell me why?

here is my function:

```
    public void onclickMenu(View view) {
    final int menuOffsetTime = 4000;
    final ImageButton menuClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_close);
    final ImageButton menuOpen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_open);
    final ImageButton expButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.export);
    final ImageButton opButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.open);
    final ImageButton setButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    final AnimationSet animationSetIn = new AnimationSet(false);
    final AnimationSet animationSetOut = new AnimationSet(false);
    Animation animationIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menu_anim_in);
    Animation animationOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menu_anim_out);
    expButton.clearAnimation();
    opButton.clearAnimation();
    setButton.clearAnimation();
    if(animationIn != null && animationOut != null) {
        animationSetIn.addAnimation(animationIn);
        animationSetOut.addAnimation(animationOut);
        animationSetIn.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animationSetOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        if(view.getId() == R.id.menu_open) {
            animationSetIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    animationSetOut.setStartOffset(menuOffsetTime);
                    animationSetOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
                    });
                    if(menuOpen.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                        opButton.startAnimation(animationSetOut);
                        setButton.startAnimation(animationSetOut);
                        if(export) {
                            expButton.startAnimation(animationSetOut);
                        }
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                menuClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                menuOpen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }, menuOffsetTime);
                    }
                }
            });
            opButton.startAnimation(animationSetIn);
            setButton.startAnimation(animationSetIn);
            opButton.setEnabled(true);
            if(export) {
                expButton.startAnimation(animationSetIn);
            }
            menuClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            menuOpen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            opButton.startAnimation(animationSetOut);
            setButton.startAnimation(animationSetOut);
            if(export) {
                expButton.startAnimation(animationSetOut);
            }
            menuClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            menuOpen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

i have this in the menu_anim_in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:duration="2000" android:fillAfter="true" />
</set>
```

and this in my menu_anim_out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="2000" android:fillAfter="true" />
</set>
```

and this is in my layout file:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
    android:id="@+id/export"
    android:onClick="onclickExport"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/export" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
    android:id="@+id/open"
    android:onClick="onclickOpen"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/open" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:onClick="onclickSettings"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/settings" />
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

onclickMenu method is unused as per your xml.

None of your imagebuttons called the onclickmenu method. so do you suppose method to be called itself?

Add this to image button if still having problems.

android:clickable="true"

hope it will help

Comment: the function is called through another button.. and the animation works so this is not the problem. the problem is that only the buttons image is moved not the whole view.. but i dont know if there is some option to move also the container which is clickable with the animation function. guess i should be able to do so with setpadding but when i try it like opButton.setPadding(100,0,0,0); it doesnt work..